# The page cannot display images？

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The frontend code has successfully obtained the image links sent by the backend, but it is unable to display them. After checking the console for "cards," it shows that the imgUrl has been successfully retrieved.When it is guaranteed, the image links are valid and free from issues such as hotlink protection.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5xu5.png)
Here is the complete code：

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoading" class="loading-message">...</div>
  <div v-else class="card-container">
    <el-backtop :right="100" :bottom="100" />
    <div class="card" v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
      <div class="add-icon" @click="addToFavorites(card)">
        <el-icon><IEpCirclePlus /></el-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="left-content">
          <img
              v-if="card.imgUrl"
              :src="card.imgUrl"
              alt="Card Image"
              class="card-image"
              @click="handleButtonClick(card.link, index)"
              @mouseover="card.isRotated = true"
              @mouseout="card.isRotated = false"
              :style="{ transform: card.isRotated ? 'rotate(360deg)' : 'rotate(0deg)' }"
          />
          <div v-else class="loading-message">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-content">
          <h3>{{ card.name }}</h3>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <p>{{ card.description }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { ElMessageBox, ElMessage } from "element-plus";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [],
      maxFavorites: 12,
      isLoading: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchDataFromApi() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("api/entertainmentTools/loadDataList");
        const responseData = response.data;
        if (responseData.status === "success" && responseData.code === 200) {
          this.cards = responseData.data.map((card) => ({ ...card, isRotated: false }));
          console.log(this.cards)
        } else {
          // 
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // 
      } finally {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
    handleButtonClick(link, index) {
      window.open(link, "_blank");
      this.cards.forEach((card, i) => {
        card.isRotated = index === i;
      });
    },
    addToFavorites(card) {
      const favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites") || "[]");
      if (favorites.length >= this.maxFavorites) {
        ElMessageBox.alert("12", "", {
          confirmButtonText: "",
          callback: () => {
            
          },
        });
      } else {
        
        const favoriteCard = { name: card.name, imgUrl: card.imgUrl, link: card.link };
        favorites.push(favoriteCard);
        localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
        ElMessage.success("success");
      }
    },
  },
  async created() {
    
    await this.fetchDataFromApi();
  },
};
</script>
```

In the first version of the code, considering the potential issues that might arise during the data retrieval and rendering process in the component, the code was modified to its current state. However, it still fails to display.

Comment: well, what's the data in `cards`?

Comment: {
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "info": "success_data",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "t1",
            "description": "te1",
            "imgurl": "https://images.xcnv.com/2023/01/28/63d5392ba7e9c.jpg",
            "link": "https://lamper.top/"
        },
        {
            "name": "t2",
            "description": "te2",
            "imgurl": "src/assets/back.png",
            "link": "https://lamper.top/"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: ahh, see the issue? the array you want is in `cards.data`, not `cards`

Comment: Yes, according to other responses, the issue has been resolved, and it was a simple mistake regarding the letter's capitalization.

Comment: sorry fellas. jk

Comment: @AlexMac - how did you know before he posted the actual data? did I miss something in the question? ahh, nevermind ... I don't look at pictures :p

Comment: looked at the picture of the data in the dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

card.imgUrl doesn't match your data key imgurl. the u is not capitalized.